# Set Range Selection of All Text Between Two Elements

Tags: javascript, copy, range, clipboard

I have a javascript program that will copy a selection in a web page.

Is it possible to set that range selection through javascript?

Ex:

```
<html>
    <h1>One</h1>
    <h2>Two</h2>
    <h3>Three</h3>
    <h4>Four</h4>
</html>
```

I would like to set the range for everything between `<h2>` and `<h4>` so that I can copy the text to the clipboard.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *I would like to set the range for everything between <h2> and <h4>*?

Comment: The same as if I was to highlight, select, and copy all the text between those two elements.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer I was looking for...
It was at https://javascript.info/selection-range

Thanks guys for the -1...  if you didn't know the answer or wanted clarification, you should have just said so.

Comment: You have to be a bit more precise when asking questions (Explanation + Example). You said between h2 and h4, but in math and programming, notion of range has inclusion. So did it include h2 and h4? h2 only, h4 only, or just h3 alone? So giving and example as Selected Result `Three` would be helpful too. We all started with the minus -1 (only guy), -2 ... -5. This is just a signal that some users give you to push to you towards the right path, but no hate. And for the answer, you could also put a sample of the solution's codes to help future coders less experienced than you on that.